# Add,Update and Delete functionality in JQGrid

Tags: jqgrid

How can I do the add,update and delete functionality in the JQgrid.Please help me

Thanks
Ritz

Answer (score 0):

I assume you know some basic commands in deleting and adding using php mysql:
Once, you click the "add button" or "delete button" this triggers or pass a value "add" or "del" to the server

editurl:"update.php?q=1",

update.php contains this line to get the value

```
$oper = $_REQUEST['oper'];
```

once you get the value you can use the switch command something like this:

```
switch ($oper){
   case "add":
     YOUR CODES HERE
   break;
   case "del":
     YOUR CODES HERE 
   break; 
}
```

hope this will help you to figure out
nphp101 [at] yc